# Does 'Density Of The Earth Remain Constant' at every level of the crust?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential

So, as I was studying Newton's Shell Theorem, I encountered a problem. This was the variation of gravitational field at an internal point.
So, the equation goes:

$d$E = $\frac{gdm}{r^2}$ along a certain direction.

E = $$\int_{}^{}dE$$

E = $\frac{G}{r^2}$ $$\int_{}^{}dm$$

Then, they integrated this to get

E = $\frac{GM}{a^3}$r

They did this by taking density as constant and then they multiplied it by volume of the new radius to get the new mass.

But, shouldn't the density change since mass and radius are both decreasing.

Comment: What are $r$, $a$, $E$, $g$ and $G$, $m$ and $M$? I can guess $a$ and $r$ are some kind of radii, what are they? $E$ looks like energy but probably it isn't. $g$ and $G$ are possibly related to gravity but what are they exactly? I would be quite certain that $M$ is the total mass of the body and $m$ is the integration variable related to that, but I can't check as I don't understand the other symbols.

Comment: OK! So, a is the radius of the sphere and r is the radius at a depth in the sphere. m is the mass of the body and M is the mass of the sphere. Hope this helps!

Comment: And E is the gravitational field.

Comment: Re *But, shouldn't the density change since mass and radius are both decreasing* -- Huh? That density is constant is a simplifying assumption. In reality, the local density inside the Earth is anything but constant, varying from around 2.6 grams/cc near the surface to over 13 grams/cc at the center, with a drastic jump in density at the core/mantle boundary.

Comment: @DavidHammen Ok! So, it's just an assumption and nothing else. Just as we assume a pseudo force in a non-inertial frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you did in those integrals is change mass with density times volume and then keep r - the radial distance from the center - as integration variable. That's where a^3 comes from after integrating it. In this model density is costant though! So, you need to consider your spherical object's density homogeneous. It's an extremely raw approximation, obviously Earth's density is far from being homogeneous.